# How to copy/paste in GNURoot terminal

Tags: android, debian, nexus

I'm on a Nexus 10 and have GNURoot Debian (newest incarnation of GNURoot) running smoothly. Now I need a way to copy commands from, say, a browser then paste them onto the GNURoot command line. I've tried everything. Not even my bluetooth keyboard or mouse will help.

Comment: Try CTRL-ALT-C ? Some linux terminals have that as their paste text shortcut

Comment: I'm not going to do a "Answer Your Question," but getting the "Clipboard" app from Store worked. I highlight the text (e.g. in Chrome), click on Share, choose Clipboard. Then in GNURoot Debian I can Shift-Ctr-V and it pastes. Now I have to figure out how to get these copy contents into my GNURoot Emacs kill ring. . .

Comment: You should certainly answer your own question. This site is not intended to only gives answers to the people who asked, it is an open source of knowledge for all.

Comment: I hesitate only because what I found out seems like a kludge. I hope a better answer comes along.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+V works as a shortcut